# Do I need a transit visa if I have a layover for only 14 hours in Kuala Lumpur?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia, kul

I would be travelling to Australia and I have a flight in mind that has a layover of 14 hours in Kuala Lumpur. I am Indian and not sure if I need to get a transit visa. I have no plans of getting out of the airport.

If I do need a transit visa as an Indian how do I get it?

Comment: Are the two flights on the same booking? Do you have checked luggage? What are the two flights (at least the airlines, ideally flight numbers)?

Answer (score 5):

As long as:

- your layover doesn't exceed 24 hours;
- you don't have to pick up your luggage (ie you're flying with either one airline, or 2 airlines that interline; or don't have check-in luggage):
- don't have to change terminals

You don't need a transit visa. Having the details of your flights would, as jcaron says, help.

I have a fair bit of experience transferring at KLIA, usually on 2 separate tickets, and the transfer desks staff are very efficient and helpful, albeit a bit cold. I always drop by the counter, even when I have my 2 boarding passes, to make sure the luggage is on its way. Saved my bacon a couple of times.

14 hours in KLIA is going to be a long wait. The airport is cold in all the meanings of the word. There isn't much to do there, and the seats are not very comfortable. It's designed to shuttle people around efficiently, but not really to keep them entertained... A very different approach from nearby Singapore.

Comment: KLIA is better than any western airport that I have been to, and overnight at the airport is certainly doable. There are lots of places to sleep and buy food etc...

Comment: Flying in the West is mostly medieval. But for a big Asian airport, KLIA is really so-so. The Malaysian Airlines are good though.

Comment: @dda Careful of your use of English/American idioms ("saved my bacon") or subjective criticisms (a bit cold). Non English-speaking visitors may not understand, and subjective negative comments, while even possibly truthful, me result in unwarranted down votes.

Answer (score 4):

Malaysia currently offers all Indian citizens visa free entry for 30 days.

https://m.economictimes.com/nri/visit/malaysia-to-allow-visa-free-entry-to-indian-citizens/articleshow/105516180.cms

Answer (score 3):

Good news - as someone else pointed out, Malaysia now allows Indian citizens to enter visa-free for up to 30 days.

Since your layover is only 14 hours, you definitely don't need a visa. Just make sure to book your flights on the same ticket or ensure your luggage is checked through by the airline.

14 hours is a long wait but at least you won't have to worry about visa formalities. Might be worth bringing a book, charging cables etc to pass the time.

Comment: You don't need to have one ticket if you fly with full-fare airlines. In Asia, most full-fare airlines interline, even when they're not in the same alliance. I do it very regularly.

Comment: You're definitely right, DDA. I hadn't considered interlining as an option. Thanks for mentioning that - travelers don't necessarily need a totally combined ticket if flying on interlining airlines. That provides more flexibility when booking diverse itineraries like Kaushik's.

Comment: Speaking from experience here! Most of my flying has been done in Asia, and KL is a frequent transfer hub for me. Generally speaking, self transfers in Asia are MUCH easier, as long as you avoid LCCs.